# Ubuntu One won't sync certain files, even though they appear in the web interface

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

The Ubuntu One web interface shows me a folder full of files, but on my laptop these files do not appear in the corresponding folder. Any new additions to this folder are correctly synced, whether the change is made through the web interface or in the folder directly. But the other files are simply ignored as if they don't exist.

I have tried stopping and restarting the service, and forcing rescanning of folders but Ubuntu One just says it is up to date, while these files refuse to be downloaded onto my local machine.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you, I can confirm that this is not an isolated problem. I've experienced similar issues. At this point I'm not 100% confident which of my files are genuinely backed up and available and which are not.

Comment: Bah, just as I feared. I ended up getting around this by manually downloading each file again from the web interface. It was only 8 files so it was doable, although what's more worrying is that there's no way of knowing if this problem exists with more of my Ubuntu One files :(

Comment: Could you please contact our Ubuntu One support staff using one.ubuntu.com/help/contact . This issue will likely need someone to look at your Ubuntu One logs to help you further troubleshoot this type of issue. When you contact us let us know if you are using Ubuntu or Windows so we can better direct you how to send your logs.

Comment: Thanks @duanedesign, I have actually had this happen again and I have contacted support. Let's see what they come up with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after contacting Ubuntu One support, I was given the following steps:

1. Stop Ubuntu One with: `u1sdtool -q`
2. Delete the following folder: `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone`
3. Restart Ubuntu One with: `u1sdtool -c`
4. Open the Ubuntu One Control Panel and reselect my sync folders.

Step 4 gave me a prompt asking me if I wanted to merge my local folder with the cloud version of the same name. After clicking "Yes", it proceeded to resync everything from scratch, which took so long I left it overnight. I can't tell if it actually downloaded or uploaded anything, but anyway by the morning it said file sync was complete.
At first glance this *seemed* ok, although I have no way of telling **for sure** if there are any more missing files elsewhere in my synced folder.

Anyway, hope this helps someone who encounters a similar problem.

Comment: I found myself experiencing the same issue again and coming back to this old post. This time around I found an easier solution: I unchecked the "sync" checkbox next to the folder, re-checked it, and it seemed to resync precisely the remaining files.