# Recover a folder through Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, data-recovery

I had a folder (a backup of my Wii homebrew actually) synced with Ubuntu One.  Unfortunately, I ran out of space on my hard drive, so I disabled Ubuntu One sync for a while and deleted the folder off the hard drive.

Months later, I have space again and would like the folder back.  I can see it though Firefox, but I see no way to download it except by downloading individual files myself through Firefox, and in this case the dense folder trees are almost as important as the files themselves.

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu One to re-download the folder to my Precise install?  Or do I have to wait until they implement this feature in the Web UI?

(No, it's not in my trash, and it was too long ago to use `extundelete`.)

Comment: If you sync with Ubuntu One again, it automatically downloads folders from your account and uploads the files/folders from your computer. I've reinstalled Ubuntu several times but I always get my files back from my Ubuntu One account when I reinstall Ubuntu One and sync folders.

Comment: So you mean I should de-sync and then re-sync?

Comment: Why not try it? Uninstall Ubuntu One and try to set it up again. Although in my case I didn't need to de-sync, after installation of Ubuntu One it automatically downloaded my uploaded folders to my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "new space" is the result of a new install on a larger hard disk, and you haven't synchronized with U1 on that install yet, then simply logging into U1 there should result in everything under the ~/Ubuntu One folder being downloaded again, and if they were in a separate folder which you synchronized, you simply have to select in the control panel to have that folder synchronized again.

If on the other hand, it is the same install you were using before, and you simply disconnected/uninstalled Ubuntu One, then deleted the folder/files in question, the files may be deleted from the server if you just log in and start syncing again. In this case, I'd recommend running these commands in a terminal:

```
$: u1sdtool -q
$: pkill -9 ubuntuone
$: mv ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.old
$: u1sdtool -c
```

This will stop ubuntuone-syncdaemon, move the metadata out of the way, and restart ubuntuone-syncdaemon and connect. When connected, it should just re-download everything, and if you have any conflicting files in `~/Ubuntu One`, or other synchronized folders, create conflict files for them.

If neither of these solutions work, and the files do end up getting deleted from the Web UI view, then ensure the client is fully synchronized with the server (all synchronized folders have the same files and those files are the same in both places), then open a support ticket at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact to get more help.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I'm still syncing and can successfully upload, so I don't know what's going on.  (I have it set to sync my documents cause my systems are usually unstable).

Comment: Yours can be the answer because I'm getting "unspecified error" when I try to mark mine XD

Answer (score 0):

I modified your solution a little bit, dobey, and used a solution from [an alternate thread's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/116639/37700).  Here is what I did:

- Stopped the Ubuntu One syncdaemon with: `u1sdtool -q`
- Deleted what appears to be the download cache/Ubuntu One temp folder? with: `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone`
- Started the  Ubuntu One syncdaemon again with: `u1sdtool -c`

This seems to have returned some other folders as well, but without the files that were in them because I deleted them before the folders.  Interesting how it behaves...  I think I'll clean up from the Web UI.